# NpgsqlDataReader - distinguish null value from "NULL" literal

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a problem with distinguishing NULL database type from "NULL" text when reading a table column from database

Sample code:

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    connection.Open();
    var query = @"SELECT array_agg(a) col FROM unnest('{NULL,""NULL""}'::text[]) a";
    using(var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var strings = rowa["col"] as string[];
                Console.WriteLine(strings[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(strings[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

both `strings[0]` and `strings[1]` are `"NULL"` but the first one should be a null value

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Npgsql's array handling is not complete yet.  It does not handle NULL elements properly.

On the surface, it seems simple enough to fix.  The array decoder strips double-quotes from each value before evaluating them.  This means that NULL (the literal) and "NULL" (the string value) both end up as the same value internally, which is then interpreted as the string value "NULL".

However, it isn't as simple as just fixing the decoder.  Once NULL and "NULL" are properly distinguished, there comes the problem of storage.  Npgsql converts arrays from PG into native .NET arrays. For example, PG text[] to .NET String[], and PG int4[] to .NET Int32[].  That's fine for String[], but you can't store a NULL value in an Int32[] (or any value type array).

To fix this problem, arrays will need to be stored in some other way (perhaps an NpgsqlArray class, which would allow NULLs and provide a suitable interface).  Unfortunately, that fix will break compatibility.

The short answer is, you just can't use arrays containing NULL elements with Npgsql for the time being.